# Error fwrite escribe cadena y basura a continuación

Tags: c, string

Tengo que realizar un programa el cual consiste en ingresar una frase y comprobar que esté bien escrita en español. Mi idea era separar el sujeto (una sola palabra), el verbo(una sola palabra) y el predicado (lo que encuentre el programa hasta el fin de la oración). De ahí, crear aparte tres archivos .txt: uno en el cual pueda ingresar una lista de sujetos, otro para un diccionario de verbos y otro de distintas frases que puedan hacer la función de predicado.

Es lo que traté de hacer y mi código principal es este:

```
//Analizar si una frase capturada por el usuario está bien escrita en español.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define cant 100

struct registro{
    char palabra_es[cant];
} est;

void Asignar_Char(char *p, char var[cant]);
int Evaluar_Sujeto(char ev_sujeto[cant]);
int Evaluar_Verbo(char ev_verbo[cant]);
int Evaluar_Predicado(char ev_predicado[cant]);

int main(){ 
    char frase[cant], sujeto[cant], verbo[cant], predicado[cant];
    char *p_sujeto, *p_verbo, *p_predicado;
    char espacio[4]=" \n\t";

    printf("Las oraciones en espa_ol por lo general contienen la siguiente estructura\n\t\t\tSUJETO + VERBO + PREDICADO\n");
    printf("Siguiendo dicha estructura, ingresa una frase: ");
    scanf("%100[^\n]", frase);
    printf("\n%s", frase);
    printf("\n\n");

    p_sujeto=strtok(frase,espacio);
    Asignar_Char(p_sujeto,sujeto);
    Evaluar_Sujeto(sujeto);

    p_verbo=strtok(NULL, espacio);
    Asignar_Char(p_verbo,verbo);
    Evaluar_Verbo(verbo);

    p_predicado=strtok(NULL, ".");
    Asignar_Char(p_predicado,predicado);
    Evaluar_Predicado(predicado);
    if (Evaluar_Sujeto(sujeto) == 0 && Evaluar_Verbo(verbo) == 0 && Evaluar_Predicado(predicado) == 0 ) printf("Oracion escrita correctamente");
    else printf("Oracion incorrecta");

    return 0;
}


void Asignar_Char(char *p, char var[cant]){
    int i=0;
    while (*p!='\0'){
        var[i]=*p;
        p++;
        i++;
    }
}



int Evaluar_Sujeto(char ev_sujeto[cant]){
    FILE *dic_s;

    dic_s=fopen("archivo_sujeto.dat", "rb");
    while (!feof(dic_s)){
        fread(&est, sizeof(est), 1, dic_s);
        if (strstr(ev_sujeto, est.palabra_es)!=NULL){
            printf("Existe");
            break;
            return 0;
        }
        else{
            printf("No existe");
            return -1;
        }

    }
    fclose(dic_s);
}



int Evaluar_Verbo(char ev_verbo[cant]){
    FILE *dic_v;

    dic_v=fopen("archivo_verbo.dat", "rb");
    while (!feof(dic_v)){
        fread(&est, sizeof(est), 1, dic_v);
        if (strstr(ev_verbo, est.palabra_es)!=NULL){
            printf("Existe");
            break;
            return 0;
        }
        else{
            printf("No existe");
            return -1;
        }
    fclose(dic_v);
}



int Evaluar_Predicado(char ev_predicado[cant]){
    FILE *dic_p;

    dic_p=fopen("archivo_predicado.dat", "rb");
    while (!feof(dic_p)){
        fread(&est, sizeof(est), 1, dic_p);
        if (strstr(ev_predicado, est.palabra_es)!=NULL){
            printf("Existe");
            return 0;
        }
        else{
            printf("No existe");
            return -1;
        }
    }
    fclose(dic_p);
}
```

Y por otro lado, cree otro programa que vaya creando los diccionarios

```
//Analizar si una frase capturada por el usuario está bien escrita en español.
//este archivo sirve para crear los diccionarios
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define cant 100

struct registro{
    char palabra_es[cant];
} est;


int main(){ 
    FILE *dic_s; //Puntero a archivo -> Diccionario de Sujeto
    //FILE *dic_v; //Puntero a archivo -> Diccionario de Verbo
    //FILE *dic_p; //Puntero a archivo -> Diccionario de Predicado


    dic_s=fopen("archivo_sujeto.txt", "a+");
    //dic_v=fopen("archivo_verbo.txt", "a+");
    //dic_p=fopen("archivo_predicado.txt", "a+");

    do{
        scanf("%s",est.palabra_es);
        if (strcmp(est.palabra_es,"x")==0 ) break;
        fwrite(&est, sizeof(est),1,dic_s);
        //fwrite(&est, sizeof(est),1,dic_v);
        //fwrite(&est, sizeof(est),1,dic_p);        
    }
    while (1);

    fclose(dic_s);
    //fclose(dic_v);
    //fclose(dic_p);
    return 0;
}
```

Mi problema está aquí en que no entiendo por qué cuando abro el diccionario .txt en sublime text, veo caracteres algo raros en hexadecimal, cuando ingreso más palabras en otro momento las funciones que evaluan la búsqueda de algún sujeto o predicado no las encuentran y se agregan caracteres basura o de plano hay otras ocasiones donde no encuentra las palabras aún a pesar de existir en los txt. ¿Me podrían ayudar a comprender esto? ¡Muchisimas gracias!

Comment: Tu codigo tiene muchas mejoras, para la comprensión en vez de un ciclo while infito con un break para terminar, utiliza una condicion de salida.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error es que **fwrite** escribe en el fichero la cantidad de datos que le indicas, en este caso e tamaño de la estructura "est". La cadena que guardas en "palabra_es", no tiene el tamaño de la estructura, aun asi fwrite seguirá escribiendo hasta completar el tamaño indicado.

La solución es darle el tamaño exacto a escribir en el fichero. En este caso el tamaño de la cadena, que podemos obtenerlo con la función "**strlen**". Quedaría asi:

```
fwrite(&est.palabra_es, strlen(est.palabra_es),1,dic_s);
```

Una solución mas sencilla sería utilizar la función "**fprintf**", de la siguiente forma:

```
fprintf(dic_s,"%s", est.palabra_es);
```

Te recomiendo añadir "**\n**" al formato **"%s\n"** para que te imprima todo en diferentes lineas en tu diccionario, aunque ya lo veras.

Aprovecho para recomendarte que cambies el ciclo do-while para hacerlo mas comprensible. Cambiandolo por while y añadiendo la condición de salida entre los parentesis no en el if y con un break.